# Can I get Outlook 2010 to alert me when an email failed SPF?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, spam-prevention

I received a very authentic looking phishing email today that almost got me.  I examined the headers and saw that it did not come from the purported source and had failed the SPF check.  Outlook 2010 didn't mention that.  Is there any way to get an alert from Outlook that the email failed the SPF check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought of using a rule to check for the string `Received-SPF: Fail` in the headers and take action from there.  Works OK so far!